# Pyspark - Divide the customers into income buckets

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

How to divide customers into income buckets using pyspark?

Assume I've 2 columns named Customer and Income having range 10K to 50K.

Now I want to Divide the customers into income buckets 10K -20K, 20K-30K etc using pyspark Data frame.

TIA!

Comment: easy approach - you can use case when (`when().otherwise()`) to create buckets using required conditions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.